# Identify which apps are draining the battery on an iPhone or other iOS device for iOS 10?

Tags: iphone, ios, battery

How to find which apps are draining the battery on an iOS device in iOS 10?

Previously in iOS 8 you could go to Settings > Battery to see a list of apps with a percentage number for rating how much battery they were responsible for using, as shown in [this posting](http://www.howtogeek.com/197074/how-to-see-which-apps-are-draining-your-battery-on-an-iphone-or-ipad/). Gone in iOS 10.

[image]

I found the Question [How to check what causes iPhone battery to drain out?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/4742/17907). But that Question and its Answers do not really describe how to identify particular problematic apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Be patient

That list of apps with percentages may not appear immediately.

You may need to actively use your device for **as much as an hour** before that list will appear. During that time you will see a message explaining that it may take “a few minutes” of usage. In my experience, that is an underestimate.

Comment: Also note that those figures represent the power usage during the indicated period (24 hours or 7 days), so if your usage in that time was unusual then the figures will be misleading.